# Why SARIMA has better accuracy on weekly dataset than on daily one?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, seasonality, fourier-transform

I am studying time series right now. So, I have this [*dataset*](https://www.kaggle.com/sumanthvrao/daily-climate-time-series-data). My aim is temperature prediction.

I've found out that ARIMA can't work with long period seasonality. So, I've resampled daily dataset into weekly. Than I create an ARIMA with *S = 52* and fit it. Here is a code (**python**):

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/DailyDelhiClimateTrain.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
df = df.resample('W').mean()

model=sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(
    df.meantemp, 
    order=(1, 1, 1),
    seasonal_order=(2, 1, 0, 52)
).fit()
```

And here is the prediction and the test data (blue - test data, red - predictions):

[image: Test and prediction plot]

As you see, the *MSE* is **6.08**.

Later, I decided to use daily format with *S = 365.25*. I didn't find solution in python, but I found a fourier approximation in **R**. So, here my daily model (**R**):

```
require(forecast)
require(data.table)

train <- read.csv("data/DailyDelhiClimateTrain.csv")
y_train = ts(train[, 2], freq=365.25)

fit <- auto.arima(y_train, seasonal=FALSE, xreg=fourier(y_train, K=15))
```

And for some reason this works much worse:
[image: Test and prediction plot]

I'm really sorry for such long introduction. My question is: why daily prediction works much worse than weekly?

Answer (score 0):

I have examined your 2 data sets ... DAILY and WEEKLY and found that your model  specification for DAILY is WAYOVERCOMPLICATED while your automatic arima approach was inadequate/deficient. Both data sets benefit from having level/step shifts and anomalies[image] empirically identified with model [image]

The Weekly series is here [image] with model[image]

IN general the results are VERY SIMILAR insofar as memory (arima structure) is omitted as it was found unnecessary to adequately characterize the series being analyzed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but looks like the models you showed were fitted on test dataset. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear. I fit my models on `Train.csv` and both screenshots in my question - are models' evaluation on `Test.csv`.